# Formatting the results of =divide as a fraction without being simplified (google sheets)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm dividing the value in one cell by a value in another cell. I want the final result to be in fraction form and not reduce to the smallest equivalent fraction.
I've figured out how to get the result of the `=divide` to format in fraction form `(# ???/???)`.
However, I cannot find a way to keep Google Sheets from simplifying it.

**For example:**
`=DIVIDE(O4,M10)` in my sheet should show `20/80` - but it converts to `1/4`.
I want to see `20/80`. The denominator will change, so I can't do this `# ??/80`.

It also cannot be formatted as text, because this fraction needs to be used in future math operations.

Tips?

Comment: yes.  the fractions are equivalent, but the 20/80 is really a ratio of (points earned/total points possible).  The spreadsheet later converts that fraction to a percentage.  But it would be nice to see the 20/80--mathematically they are the same, but in terms of a ratio, it communicates something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead of `DIVIDE`,

```
=QUERY(O4/M10,"select Col1 format Col1 '# ?/"&M10&"'")
```

- M10:Denominator
- O4:Numerator
- By dynamically formatting Denominator to always be M10 through `QUERY`,We preserve the  underlying number as well as the format(as opposed to  `TEXT` ,Where we cannot change the underlying real value.)

Comment: Sheets still simplifies the fraction instead of leaving it in its ratio form.

Comment: Bingo!  Setting Number format to Automatic did the trick!  Awesome Work!